# Delete from source bucket after duplicating into another bucket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I need to create a lambda function where it selects an image in a **source bucket** and resizes it. After this is done it puts the resized image into **another bucket**. I have been following a tutorial on the aws website but now I need to add the feature so it deletes the original image from the original bucket.

Have tried it via many different ways but can't get it working. Help please.

```
    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                },
                next);
            },
        function transform(response, next) {
            gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
                // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
                var scalingFactor = Math.min(
                    MAX_WIDTH / size.width,
                    MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
                );
                var width  = scalingFactor * size.width;
                var height = scalingFactor * size.height;

                // Transform the image buffer in memory.
                this.resize(width, height)
                    .toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) {
                        if (err) {
                            next(err);
                        } else {
                            next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
                        }
                    });
            });
            },
            function upload(contentType, data, next) {
                // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
                s3.putObject({
                        Bucket: dstBucket,
                        Key: dstKey,
                        Body: data,
                        ContentType: contentType
                    },
                    next);
            },
            function deleteOrig(err) {
              s3.deleteObject({
                Bucket: srcBucket,
                Key: srcKey
              }){
                if(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              }
            }
        ], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(
                    'Unable to resize ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
                    ' due to an error: ' + err
                );
            } else {
                console.log(
                    'Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
                );
            }

            callback(null, "message");
        }
    );
};
```

IN LAMBDA, RETURNS SUCCESS WITH FOLLOWING LOG:

```
START RequestId: f4a00fce-c283-4801-a902-03d450db8a8d Version: $LATEST
2019-01-29T10:07:19.012Z    f4a00fce-c283-4801-a902-03d450db8a8d    Reading options from event:
 { Records: 
   [ { eventVersion: '2.0',
       eventSource: 'aws:s3',
       awsRegion: 'us-west-2',
       eventTime: '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
       eventName: 'ObjectCreated:Put',
       userIdentity: { principalId: 'AIDAJDPLRKLG7UEXAMPLE' },
       requestParameters: { sourceIPAddress: '127.0.0.1' },
       responseElements: 
        { 'x-amz-request-id': 'C3D13FE58DE4C810',
          'x-amz-id-2': 'FMyUVURIY8/IgAtTv8xRjskZQpcIZ9KG4V5Wp6S7S/JRWeUWerMUE5JgHvANOjpD' },
       s3: 
        { s3SchemaVersion: '1.0',
          configurationId: 'testConfigRule',
          bucket: 
           { name: 'ciansource',
             ownerIdentity: { principalId: 'A3NL1KOZZKExample' },
             arn: 'arn:aws:s3:::ciansource' },
          object: 
           { key: 'football.jpg',
             size: 1024,
             eTag: 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e',
             versionId: '096fKKXTRTtl3on89fVO.nfljtsv6qko' } } } ] }
2019-01-29T10:07:19.281Z    f4a00fce-c283-4801-a902-03d450db8a8d    { AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:577:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
  message: 'Access Denied',
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  region: null,
  time: 2019-01-29T10:07:19.279Z,
  requestId: '7FDDB3FAD06B6A81',
  extendedRequestId: '6N6cxCFzgupDhpukxcVHOaFECYKl/0cQx7lc40qVGYnYr2efnXarfQ9ztQ3/nU8Fu6WpRurJ7Ps=',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 10.888386530079242 } 'AccessDenied: Access Denied\n    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:577:35)\n    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)\n    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)\n    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)\n    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)\n    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)\n    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)\n    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)\n    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)'
END RequestId: f4a00fce-c283-4801-a902-03d450db8a8d
REPORT RequestId: f4a00fce-c283-4801-a902-03d450db8a8d  Duration: 273.72 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms     Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 39 MB
```

Comment: Don't just dump your whole code here. Just paste the code you use for deleting and state why it isn't working. Are you getting an error?

Comment: @NinadGaikwad When i run the invoke command in cmd, i just get StatusCode: 202. But when I check the buckets, everything works except the original one doesnt delete

Comment: Check the logs of the lambda and see the error in detail.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad Ive edited the question to show the log

Comment: Isn't the log about `putObject`? (`eventName: 'ObjectCreated:Put'`)

Comment: There is no error. For some reason your delete function isn't being called. You can start debugging it by making it print out a message on console as soon as it starts executing the function.

Comment: Yes the delete function wasnt being called, now it is. Sorry for that, I have updated the log

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, I hadn't given the role I was using permission to delete from s3. When I added that policy it fixed it. Thanks for all who helped!